# Spring security does'nt work.Error is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

This is my security xml file.

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd"> 
    <http auto-config="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="ROLE_USER" />  
            <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />  
        <form-login 
            always-use-default-target="true" 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/welcome" 
            login-processing-url="/checkUser"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="username" 
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"  
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-url="/login?logout" /> 
        <csrf/>
    </http> 
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" /> 
                <user name="admin" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" /> 
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

This is my CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler class and this class implement  from AuthenticationSuccessHandler interface.

**CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler**

```
package com.mehman.puyment.security; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException { 
        System.out.println("!***********************************************!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define bean with id authenticationSuccessHandler and class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler in spring-security.xml

Comment: i created bean in servlet-dispatcher.xml file.

Comment: <bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.mehman.puyment.security.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

Comment: sorry..your are right.problem solved.thanks advance your help.